# How to identify short tags using XmlTextReader in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, tags, short, xmltextreader

Given below is a sample code that reads an XML and writes it. The output XML is invalid because it fails to detect short-tags like `"<test attrib="123" />`. Is there any way I can detect such tags using XmlTextReader?

```
       while (reader.Read()){
              switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                            writer.WriteAttributes(reader, false);
                            break;
                        } 
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                    case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                        writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                        writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                        break;
                }
          }
```

Comment: What's wrong with "short tags"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What problem is being caused by the "short tags"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the element is empty:

```
   case XmlNodeType.Element:
       {                         
           writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
           writer.WriteAttributes(reader, false);
           if (reader.IsEmptyElement) writer.WriteEndElement();
           break;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `XmlTextReader.IsEmptyElement`. It returns true if (and only if) the element is a self-closing element. See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.isemptyelement.aspx) for more information.